# Why doesn't my facebook messenger show filter buttons during a live video call?

Tags: facebook-messenger, filter, video-calling

Below is a screenshot from an Oppo f1s smartphone which has the desired feature.

It shows a button which allows me to add filters during a live video call in facebook messenger.

But any other smartphone I see does not have the feature eg. Moto G3.

How can I have this feature in any phone? What is my smartphone lacking?

[image: Screenshot from Oppo smartphone]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>